# Method return type to fulfill multiple interfaces

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, return-value

Is it possible to specify a method which returns a object that implements two or multiple interfaces?

Say we have the following interfaces:

```
interface FooBar {
    [Foo] & [Bar] getFooBar();
}

interface Foo {
    void doFoo();
}

inteface Bar {
    void doBar();
}
```

Implementors of `FooBar` need to provide the method `getFooBar()` that returns an instance of a type which fullfills `Foo` as well as `Bar`.

What I tried so far is to do it with generics:

```
interface FooBar {
    <T extends Foo & Bar> T getFooBar()
}

class SomeImplementor implements FooBar {
    private FooAndBarImpl fSomeField;

    public <T extends Foo & Bar> T getFooBar() {
        return fSomeField;
    }

}
```

Given that `FooAndBarImpl` is some type provided by a framework or library and implements `Foo` and `Bar` this I think should work. However, it doesn't, because "FooAndBarImpl cannot be converted to T". Why is that? The contract implied by `getFooBar()` is not broken as I see it.

Another solution would be to define a new interface that extends `Foo` and `Bar` and to use that as return type. I just don't see much sense in returning a empty wrapper for the `fSomeField` in the `getFooBar()` implementation.

**EDIT:**

Would appreciate it if someone could explain why the generics approach doesn't work. I just don't see it.

Comment: updated my answer after you updated, to include (what i consider) a pretty good explanation of the generics issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make T a class parameter:

```
class SomeImplementor<T extends Foo & Bar> implements FooBar {
    private T fSomeField;

    public T getFooBar() {
        return fSomeField;
    }

}
```

As to why your generics approach didn't work. Lets create the following two classes that implement `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class A implements Bar, Foo{
   private int a;
   ...
}
class B implements Bar, Foo{
   private String b;
   ...
}
class SomeImplementor implements FooBar {
   private A someField;
   public <T extends Foo & Bar> T getFooBar() {
      return someField;
   }
}
```

So we should now be able to execute the following:

```
SomeImplementor s = new SomeImplementor();
A a = s.getFooBar();
B b = s.getFooBar();
```

Although `getFooBar()` returns an object of type A, which has no valid cast to type B (where will the `String` member come from?), even though B fulfills the requirement of `<T extends Foo & Bar>`, i.e. is a valid `T`.

In short, the compiler (remember, generics is a *compile-time* mechanism) can't guarantee that every `T` of type `<T extends Foo & Bar>` can have an assignment to it of type `A`. Which is exactly the error you see - the compiler can't convert the given A to every valid T.

Answer (score 2):

> > Another solution would be to define a new interface that extends Foo and Bar and to use that as return type.

I would say go for this option.

Comment: And create a wrapper since the type is defined by a framework?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a wrapper?  if `fSomeField ` is an instance of something which implements your new combined FooBar interface, why use a wrapper?

Comment: It's type is provided by a library, ie., I can't change the code.

Comment: The problem with this is that, in the OP's situation, there are already classes/interfaces that subclass `Foo` and `Bar`, so if the OP created an interface that extended `Foo` and `Bar`, already existing interfaces (which don't extend the OP's interface) could not be returned from the OP's method.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {
    FooBar getFooBar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return a container to provide Foo and Bar.

```
public class Container{
   private FooBarBam foobar;
   public Bar asBar(){
      return foobar;
   }
   public Foo asFoo(){
      return foobar;
   }
}
```

This way your code would not have to implement a third interface. Downside is that it is an additional layer of indirection.

As for why the generic approach does not work: there is no way to provide the type of T and the compiler can't just guess its type, so resolving T is not possible.

davin's answer looks good but also requires a public class/interface which implements Foo and Bar to work.

**Update:**

The problem is that the compiler does not know that the type of T should be FooAndBarImpl, it would have to guess and a guessing compiler leads to bad and unpredictable code.

Even a hack using Lists wont compile since the & operator is not supported. While it should be possible to implement it looks like generics currently don't support multiple bounds within return types.

```
//Does not compile expecting > after Foo
List<? extends Foo & Bar> getFooBar(){
    final List<FooAndBarImpl> l = new ArrayList<FooAndBarImpl>();
    l.add(new FooAndBarImpl());
    return l;
}
```

Comment: That's what I don't get: the compiler knows that the type of `fSomeField` implements `Foo` and `Bar` and therefore should be able to infer that it is a subtype of `Foo` and `Bar`, no?