# Method return type to fulfill multiple interfaces - Again

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, return-value

Today I ran into the following problem. Consider the setup:

```
interface A {
    void foo();
}

interface B {
    void bar();
}

class Impl implements A,B {

    public void foo() { }
    public void bar() { }

}

class Usage {

    void worksAsParameter(){
        acceptIt(new Impl());
    }

    <T extends A & B> void acceptIt(T foo){

    }

    <T extends A & B> T returnIt(){
        return new Impl(); // <-- Compile error
    }

}
```

The code compiles except in the last statement as marked. Eclipse gives me the `error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Impl to T`

My question is: Why is `Impl` assignable to `T` when given as a parameter (shown in `worksAsParameter` but not when `T` is a return type ?
And also, what expression aside from `null` will satisfy the type `T` in the case where `Impl` does not?

Please note that this question is not the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747292/method-return-type-to-fullfill-multiple-interfaces) although similar.

Edit: Fixed typo.

=== Summary ===
It would seem I had misunderstood how generic return types work. I will try to write up my new understanding of it.
Lets look at the issue:

```
<T extends A & B> T returnIt(){
    return new Impl(); // <-- Compile error
}
```

My initial assumption was that the implementing class (in this case `Usage`) decided on the concrete type for `T` with the restriction that it must extend `A` and `B`. Apparently it is the caller/callsite that gets to decide what `T` is and `Usage` must supply a value that is assignable to `T`. However, as `T` is a compile time deal only it is impossible to supply such a value aside from `null` (as it is assignable to anything).
Afaik this means that any code of the form will only ever be able to return `null`:

```
<T extends A> T returnIt(){
    return x; // <-- Compile error
}
```

A fairly unintuitive feature that is hopefully more useful in a different setting. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason

```
<T extends A & B> T returnIt(){
    return new Impl();
}
```

doesn't compile is that T could be any class which extends A and B. You happen to know there is only one possible class at the moment, but the compile doesn't "know" this.

e.g.

```
class AB extends A, B { }

Usage usage = ...
AB ab = usage.<AB>returnIt(); // T is AB not Impl.
```

You can force the issue with

```
<T extends A & B> T returnIt(){
    return (T) new Impl(); // unchecked cast warning.
}
```

but a better solution is

```
Impl returnIt(){
    return new Impl();
}
```

---

This defines two generics

```
<T extends A, B>
```

`T extends A` and also `B extends Object`

What you may have intended is

```
<T extends A & B>
```

where T must extend A and B.

Comment: Thank you. The question remains the same though :)

Comment: Why would your AB example ever work ? It enforces from the callers side that all returned objects must be a subclass of AB. Also, the second part of my question is, is it possible to construct anything that works (other than null) that works? My intention is to promise that the returned object implements A and B. No more no less.

Comment: T can be any class which extends A & B and AB extends A & B.

Comment: In that case you need to use the cast `(T)` and be aware that the caller could expect a specific class. Or you don't use generics and use `Impl`

Comment: Am I to read that as a no then ? That `null` will be the only value its possible to return ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like below to avoid compilation error.

```
       <T extends A & B> T returnIt(Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(new Impl());
    }
```